# How to fix "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute in powershell"

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to insert a variable with multiple values into another variable to add the values to a table. But the enumeration operation won't execute

I've tried making arrays, arraylists, but nothing has worked

```
[guid]$subscriptionId = "blank for example" 
[guid]$tenantId = "blank for example" 


Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

$resgrp = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | select ResourceGroupName,Location
foreach ($res in $resgrp)
{
    $timestmp = Get-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $res.ResourceGroupName | select Timestamp
    $resgrp.Add($timestmp)
}
```

I expect to see a formatted table with:

```
ResourceName   Location  Timestamp
------------   --------  ---------
etc.           etc.      etc.
```

Comment: This is a limitation of .NET.  You can't modify a collection while it's being enumerated.  It looks like what you're actually trying to do is to create a single object with the combined properties of the two cmdlet calls.  In that case you should look at [Add-member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member?view=powershell-6) and possibly [creating custom objects](https://devops-collective-inc.gitbook.io/the-big-book-of-powershell-gotchas/new-object-psobject-vs.-pscustomobject)

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify a list that you're currently iterating over.

Instead, what you'll want to do is create a new list comprising the original input objects + the added timestamp:

```
$resgrpWithTimestamp = $resgrp |Select ResourceGroupName,Location,@{Name='Timestamp';Expression={Get-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName |Select -Expand Timestamp}}
```